# Maven-ejb-plugin. How to exclude artifact from generated client?

Tags: java, maven

I have a  EJB  maven module. And it has some dependencies with compile scope. How I can exclude this dependencies from generated client?

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <generateClient>true</generateClient>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thing like this which is intended for excluding transitive dependencies:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you have dependencies like this which you don't like to be packaged into your EJB Module (which is usually a jar file):

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

It might be useful to define the [scope of the dependency as *provided* like this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**Update:**
May be you can try to use the optional flag:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: No, dependency must be packaged into `ejb.jar` (using scope `compile`), but it must be excluded from generated client. Ho to achieve this?

Comment: If the optional does not work you need to make different modules for ejb and client and separate configuration.